# Image.asset - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to use an image, the code gives me the following error:

[image: error]

But the code is working only with another image. When I try to use this one, it fails.
This is the code:

```
Center(
            child: Image.asset(
                'assets/perigo.png'),
          )
```

Pubspeck.yaml file:

```
assets:
    - assets/
```

Comment: is that the image that's giving you the issue (perigo.png)? Are you sure it isn't corrupted or not a valid image (maybe it just has the extension but not an image)? can you preview it in another software? what size is it? Sorry - too many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your image ("perigo.png") is correct, Type of image etc.

---

This work for me. try:

- stop the running app and re-run it. (Not restart)

If it's not,

- set your `Pubspeck.yaml` file like this,

  ```
  assets:
    - assets/perigo.png
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the Pubspeck.yaml file and It worked.